# Bash command - how to grep and then truncate but keep grep-ed part?

Tags: bash, terminal, grep

**I am trying to splice out a particular piece of string. I used:**

```
myVar=$(grep --color 'GACCT[ATCG]*AGGTC' FILE.txt | cat)
```

**then, I used the code below to remove everything before and after my desired portion.**

```
myVar1=$(echo ${myVar##*GACCT})
echo ${myVar1%%AGGTC*}
```

**The code is working however, it cuts off the GACCT and AGGTC at the beginning and end of the desired fragmen that I want to keep. Is there anyway to cut the beginning and end off while still keeping the GACCT and AGGTC?**

Thank you!

Comment: I suspect you just want `grep -o`

Comment: Why are you using `--color` and `cat`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a GNU `grep`, you can make use of

```sh
myVar=$(grep --color=never -oP 'GACCT\K[ATCG]+(?=AGGTC)' FILE.txt)
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/SGZuA6):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='GACCTAAATTTGGGCCCAGGTC'
 
# Original script
myVar=$(grep --color 'GACCT[ATCG]*AGGTC' <<< "$s" | cat)
myVar1=$(echo ${myVar##*GACCT})
echo ${myVar1%%AGGTC*}
# => AAATTTGGGCCC

# My suggestion:
grep --color=never -oP 'GACCT\K[ATCG]+(?=AGGTC)' <<< "$s"
# => AAATTTGGGCCC
```

With `--color=never`, your matches are not colored.

The `-o` option outputs the matched texts, and the `P` option enables the PCRE regex engine. It is necessary here since the regex pattern contains specific operators, like `\K` and `(?=...)`.

*More details*

- `GACCT` - a literal string
- `\K` - operator that makes the regex engine "forget" what has been consumed
- `[ATCG]+` - one or more letters from the set
- `(?=AGGTC)` - a positive lookahead that requires an `AGGTC` string immediately to the right of the current location.

Note you can get this result with `pcregrep`, too, if you install it:

```sh
myVar=$(pcregrep -o 'GACCT\K[ATCG]+(?=AGGTC)' FILE.txt)
```